# Is this formula correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I (perhaps incorrectly) derived the following formula:
$$\sigma_0\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{n}+\frac{i}{\pi}\ln\left(\frac{e^{\frac{i\pi}{n}(2x-n+1)}-e^{\frac{i\pi}{n}(3x-2n+2)}}{e^{\frac{i\pi}{n}(x-n+1)}-1}\right)\right]$$

Where $\sigma_0(x)$ is the number of divisors of $x$. Does this look familiar? If not, how might I go about computing values to disprove the identity?

Context: My method was to construct a sum of Fourier series for square waves of period $n$ that evaluate to $1$ between $n-1$ and $n$, and 0 everywhere else. Using some trig identities I managed to "simplify" the expression from a double infinite sum to a single one. Is this a valid approach?

Comment: I feel like an inclusion of the derivation might help us... anecdotally, I'm kind of surprised to see the number-of-divisors function look this, well, "nasty" when continued to non-integer values like this.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer Sure, I'll take this opportunity to write it up fully. Might take a while..

I also just realised I could simplify the $e^{\pi i}$ terms to (-1)

Comment: How do you define $\sigma _0$ for non-integer values?

Comment: @YiFan At the moment it doesn't, it just gives you the $\sigma_0$ of the nearest integer

Answer (score 1):

More a comment than an answer,
but easier to enter here.

This reminds me of
Ramanujan's sum:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_sum

In particular,

$-\sigma_0(n)
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\ln(k)}{k}c_k(n)
$
where
$c_k(n)
=\sum\limits_{a=1,(a, k)=1}^n e^{2\pi ia n/k}
$.